# GWT development mode autoscroll un tick

Tags: gwt

I would like to know if there is a setup or configuration file command where I could disable/untick the "Auto-Scroll" option which starts up 'ticked' when i run GWT development mode, and also on the tab index(Chrome) or index(FF)

- For anyone who face lags or freezes on development mode, just un-tick the Auto-Scroll option on GWT development mode window when it starts,and also on the browser tab on development mode window, it does stop hanging/freezing in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is hard-coded to `true`. But there are hacks to turn it of.

- Create a file with name `SwingLoggerPanel` and with package name `com.google.gwt.dev.shell.log;`.
- Add this package to your  application.
- Copy paste `SwingLoggerPanel` code from dev jar
- Change  the `line no 322` from `autoScroll = new JCheckBox("Auto-scroll",
  true);` to `autoScroll = new JCheckBox("Auto-scroll", false);`

You now have your auto scroll disabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible: the checkbox default value is hard-coded: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.6.0/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/log/SwingLoggerPanel.java (search for `JCheckBox` or `Auto-Scroll`)